# How to ask Allah to conceal my sins

Tags: allah, sin, dua

I have lied and committed many sins. This was because I was not connected with Allah in the way I am now. Alhumdullilah I was shown back to the right path, but I’m fearful that my past lied and deceit may catch up to me.
For example: I lied to my wife about something major, and now I’m scared she’ll discover the truth.

Is there a way to ask Allah to conceal my lies so that I am not exposed for the sins I committed?

Answer (score 0):

Repent

Avoid Sins

Don't talk about your sins to others

**Don't search or reveal sins of others.**

Try to cover sins of fellow Muslims if you come to know about them.

And Allaah knows the best.